# PHP DOM code adding children to children, instead of adding all children to same parent as siblings

Tags: php, xml, appendchild

I have copied code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps#domxml) to create xml with one parent (markers) and multiple siblings (markers).  The code I copied is:

```
    // Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
//header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
      // Add to XML document node
      $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
      $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
      $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
    }

}
```

The example shows output like this, which is what I want, where all the children are siblings:

```
<markers>
<marker id="1" name="Love.Fish" address="580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" type="restaurant"/>
<marker id="2" name="Young Henrys" address="76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW" lat="-33.898113" lng="151.174469" type="bar"/>
<marker id="3" name="Hunter Gatherer" address="Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW" lat="-33.840282" lng="151.207474" type="bar"/>
<marker id="4" name="The Potting Shed" address="7A, 2 Huntley Street, Alexandria, NSW" lat="-33.910751" lng="151.194168" type="bar"/>
<marker id="5" name="Nomad" address="16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.879917" lng="151.210449" type="bar"/>
<marker id="6" name="Three Blue Ducks" address="43 Macpherson Street, Bronte, NSW" lat="-33.906357" lng="151.263763" type="restaurant"/>
<marker id="7" name="Single Origin Roasters" address="60-64 Reservoir Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.881123" lng="151.209656" type="restaurant"/>
<marker id="8" name="Red Lantern" address="60 Riley Street, Darlinghurst, NSW" lat="-33.874737" lng="151.215530" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

But I get this, where the marker8 is a child of marker7, which is a child of marker6, ......... and only marker1 is a direct child of markers:

```
   <markers>
  <marker id="1" name="Love.Fish" address="580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" type="restaurant">
     <marker id="2" name="Young Henrys" address="76 Wilford Street, Newtown, NSW" lat="-33.898113" lng="151.174469" type="bar">
        <marker id="3" name="Hunter Gatherer" address="Greenwood Plaza, 36 Blue St, North Sydney NSW" lat="-33.840282" lng="151.207474" type="bar">
           <marker id="4" name="The Potting Shed" address="7A, 2 Huntley Street, Alexandria, NSW" lat="-33.910751" lng="151.194168" type="bar">
              <marker id="5" name="Nomad" address="16 Foster Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.879917" lng="151.210449" type="bar">
                 <marker id="6" name="Three Blue Ducks" address="43 Macpherson Street, Bronte, NSW" lat="-33.906357" lng="151.263763" type="restaurant">
                    <marker id="7" name="Single Origin Roasters" address="60-64 Reservoir Street, Surry Hills, NSW" lat="-33.881123" lng="151.209656" type="restaurant">
                       <marker id="8" name="Red Lantern" address="60 Riley Street, Darlinghurst, NSW" lat="-33.874737" lng="151.215530" type="restaurant" />
                    </marker>
                 </marker>
              </marker>
           </marker>
        </marker>
     </marker>
  </marker>
```

How can I correct this so that all the "**marker**"s are all siblings and direct children of "**markers**"?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your output. First structure is generated using same level array: https://eval.in/970678.

Comment: I tried your code with the languages.  I had to remove the header line, and when I did, had the same result as with my code. It must be the removal of the header line that is causing the problem. If I include the header line, I get, "This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 11: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."  I can't seem to get rid of this error, even if I put the header right after <?php.  FYI, the code is in a CodeIgniter model.

Comment: I also tried your code in PHPFiddler, and got the same error on the Header statement. If I take it out, I get the same marker child of marker which is a child of marker......

Comment: It might be the CodeIgniter framework. Regardless of header, even if you save XML to file with `file_put_contents('/path/to/output.xml', $dom->saveXML());` and not echo to browser, vanilla PHP cannot nest children using posted code. Can you try in base/vanilla PHP?

Comment: @parfait - Thanks so much for all your help.  I found a codeigniter googlemap library, where it is SO much easier: http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/